# Constraint to limit count of value to one per group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with an Employee_ID, Position_ID, and Active_Status.  The Employee_ID and Position_ID are both foreign keys and a combined key in this table.  An employee may hold several positions but they should never have more than one active position at any given time.  Is there a constraint that can achive this limitation?

Clearly incorect code below but something like,

```
CONSTRAINT chkStatus CHECK ((SELECT COUNT(ACTIVE) FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAIL WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID) = 1)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Appologies, apparently I did not include the tag, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multirow check constraints (aka assertions) are not supported by any major RDBMS.

[SQL Assertions / Declarative multi-row constraints](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028)

---

You could use filtered/partial `UNIQUE` index instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON EMPLOYEE_DETAIL(Employee_id) WHERE ACTIVE = 'Y';
```

> [Unique Partial Indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/partialindex.html)
>
> A partial index definition may include the UNIQUE keyword. If it does, then SQLite requires every entry in the index to be unique. This provides a mechanism for enforcing uniqueness across some subset of the rows in a table.